# Rails: selectively replace hostname and parameters for canonical links

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**Is there a way to selectively replace parameters and the hostname in a Rails URL in a clean fashion?**

Background:

I need to generate `<link rel="canonical" href="http://...">` links in my app in cases where the current page is not canonical (e.g. an extra param is present in the URL, or the hostname might be an i18n subdomain like `es.mysite.com`)

I like being able to use `url_for(params.except(:foo))` to cleanly remove parameters; this seems to make intelligent use of my routes to correctly munge the URL, and I feel like this is the most bullet-proof way to prevent breakage when URLs or parameters change in the future.

But for fixing the hostname, I don't see a nice clean way to go in and directly replace (for example) `es.mysite.com` with `mysite.com`, outside of operating on the string-level and employing regexes.

It's not the end of the world to parse the string manually, but I'd be delighted to learn that there's a way to do something like: `url_for(params.except(:foo), with_host: "mysite.com")`

Answer (score 2):

To massage URLs look at either Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) module, or the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) gem. Both let you get down and dirty and tear apart URLs and rebuild them.

This is a little example from IRB using Addressable::URI:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'addressable/uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> uri = Addressable::URI.parse(
irb(main):003:1*       "http://example.com/a/b/c/?one=1&two=2#foo"
irb(main):004:1>   )
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x80c1561c URI:http://example.com/a/b/c/?one=1&two=2#foo>
irb(main):005:0> uri.query_values
=> {"one"=>"1", "two"=>"2"}
irb(main):006:0> uri.query_values={'one'=>2,'two'=>1}
=> {"one"=>2, "two"=>1}
irb(main):007:0> uri
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x80c1561c URI:http://example.com/a/b/c/?one=2&two=1#foo>
```

Here's how to deal with the host:

```
irb(main):008:0> uri.host
=> "example.com"
irb(main):009:0> uri.host = 'foo.com'
=> "foo.com"
irb(main):010:0> uri
=> #<Addressable::URI:0x80c1561c URI:http://foo.com/a/b/c/?one=2&two=1#foo>
```

URI is built-in and works OK but it is showing some age. Addressable conforms to the RFC and is very powerful and full-featured.